# converting aac to mp3 via command line

Tags: mp3, aac, command-line

## Original Question

Is there some cli tool to convert aac files from the iTunes Store (no DRM) to mp3?

## Update 1

### MP3 to MP3

I installed `libavcodec-unstripped-52` and get a little further.

When I try to encode MP3 files with it:
It says `[mp3 @ 0x997cde0]Header missing`.

lame also had problems since the tags are ID3v2, is it possible that the libmp3lame does not support that either?

Should I convert the tags or what can I do to get this working?

### AAC to MP3

This went through, but there are no headers in the resulting MP3 file. How can I get the headers in there?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The most appropriate command line tool is the ffmpeg utility available to be installed via the software center/synaptic manager.

A command line example would be something like this for Constant Bitrate Mode (CBR):

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.m4a -c:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 190k outputfile.mp3
```

Or even better for Variable Bitrate Mode (VBR):

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.m4a -c:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -q:a 2 outputfile.mp3
```

More information on mp3 encoding with FFmpeg can be seen here:

[FFmpeg MP3 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3)

Comment: okay, that looks very good. My ffmpeg just says "Unknown encoder 'mp3'". I have lame installed.

Comment: solved it by installing libavcodec-unstripped-52, but now I got the next problem. (I added it to the original question.)

Comment: have a look in synaptic - have you libfaad2 installed?  Generally I use sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras to ensure all relevant codecs are installed

Comment: libfaad2 is installed, but I got by the mp3 with with libavcodec-unstripped-52 I believe.

Comment: I'm on natty - this is how I converted a downloaded aac file

sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-52 followed by ffmpeg -i inputfile.m4a -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160 outputfile.mp3

Comment: Maverick here, but I got it with the same line. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe one more comment, it should actually be `-ab 160k` and not `-ab 160`. The `-ab` parameter takes bits, not kilobits.

Answer (score 8):

If your Linux complain that he doesn't have an mp3 codec, try this:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.m4a -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k outputfile.mp3
```

Note that the `-ab` parameters takes in bits per second, not kilobits per second.

Comment: As above, note it should actually be `-ab 160k` and not `-ab 160`. The `-ab` parameter takes bits, not kilobits.